# Burp: changeing the hostname of a target / branch

Tags: burp

I've collected in a manual test a lot of URIs below a target. As the host is a local environment, I'd like to run the same scan against the same set of URIs in the QA environment. Hence, the hostname of https://:4443/app/... should change in https://:443/app/...

Comment: You can do this with the [Copy Site Map](https://github.com/pajswigger/copy-sitemap) extension

Comment: Oh, that looks pretty good. Thanks!